# Flask not rendering some elements in HTML page

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm not seeing the style or link elements in Chrome Dev Tools.
I've been trying to get the favicon to show, but it looks like it is never rendered.

Edit: I did more testing. There is an h1 element that also does not render. It does not appear in the HTML at all in Dev tools.

Why is Flask not including them on the web page?

This is my (full) base.html

```html
<!-- Base HTML File -->
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}
<html>
    <head>
        {% block title %}
        {{ base['title'] }}
        {% endblock %}
        <style>
          .navbar-toggle {
              position: absolute;
              right: 0;
            }
          @media (max-width: 786px) {
              .navbar-brand {
                  padding-right: 60px;
                  height: auto;
              }
          }
        </style>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('favicon') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block navbar %} <!-- Nav Bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 16px;" class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">My Website!</a>
              
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            
            {% if base['search_bar'] %}
            <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
              <div class="input-group">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
                  {{ base['search_bar'].hidden_tag() }}
                  <div class="input-group">
                      {{ base['search_bar'].search_for(class="form-control", placeholder="Search with Barcode", size="25") }}
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      {{ base['search_bar'].start_search(class="btn btn-primary") }}
                    </span>
                  </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </form>
              </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div><!-- /nav bar form -->
            {% endif %}

            <div id="main-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('signup') }}">Register</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ current_user.username }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        {% endblock %} <!-- Nav Bar -->
        <br/>
        <h1>TESTING</h1>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %} <!-- Main Content -->
        
    </body>
</html>
```

This returns the path to the favicon.ico file (in `app\static\favicon.ico`). The print statement never prints during a request.

```py
import os
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    print(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'))
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico')
```

I also set a directory for "static" in `app/__init__.py`

```py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./templates', static_folder='./static')
```

Screenshot from Chrome

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tS1p.png)

Networking Dev tools also does not show any 404 errors.

Comment: You've got a typo in your first paragraph.  What's the first thing?  Looks like there's a missing word.  What does the `View Page Source` look like?  Did you take some some code out of the header for your example?  Bootstrap is in your screen shot but not in your code.

Comment: Fixed the typo. This is all of the code in the header. I use bootstrap later in the body of base.html for a navbar, I think the import statement adds that stylesheet.

Comment: @Sobigen I added more info to the post. It seems like there are elements outside of the head that do not appear in the web page at all either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across this page: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html
And I added a block for the head. It got rid of my bootstrap css but I can edit the header now. I think its the same for the h1 element, it needs to be in a 'body' block.